# regular expression : ignore html tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, search

I have HTML content like this:

`<p>The bedding was hardly <strong>able to cover</strong> it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>`

Here's a complete version of the HTML.
http://collabedit.com/gkuc2

I need to search the string `hardly able to cover` (just an example), I want to ignore any HTML tags inside the string I'm looking for. Because in the HTML file there's HTML tags inside the string and a simple search won't find it.

The use case is: I have two versions of a file:

- An HTML file with text and tags
- The same file but with the raw text only (removed any tags and extra spaces)

The sub-string that I want to search (the needle) is from the text version (that doesn't contain any HTML tag) and I want to find it's position in the HTML version (the file that has tags).

What is the regular expression that would work?

Comment: Where is your `Complete` HTML

Comment: simple: you don't use regexes. regexes + html = bad idea. use a DOM parser, or strip ALL the tags and then regex on the plaintext.

Comment: As @MarcB said, this is generally not where you'd use RegEx. if you're looking for a simple find though, you could try putting `(.*)` in between each word you're looking for. this might only work about 40% correct though: i.e. `hardly(.*)able(.*)to(.*)cover`

Comment: I would say the only way to do this is to build a tree of some kind. A tree of positions.

Comment: @MarcB I already use the PHP DOM extension to do some stuff on the HTML file (for example get the raw text without tags). But now I need to get a substring from the plain text and find it in the HTML version.

Comment: @Tushar I just added a link to the complete HTML file http://collabedit.com/gkuc2

Comment: What do you mean by "find the position in the HTML file"? You want to pinpoint a set of nodes containing your needle and do something with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this between each letter:

```
(?:<[^>]+>)*
```

and replace the spaces with:

```
(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*\s+(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*
```

Like:

```
h(?:<[^>]+>)*a(?:<[^>]+>)*r(?:<[^>]+>)*d(?:<[^>]+>)*l(?:<[^>]+>)*y(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*\s+(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*a(?:<[^>]+>)*b(?:<[^>]+>)*l(?:<[^>]+>)*e(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*\s+(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*t(?:<[^>]+>)*o(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*\s+(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*c(?:<[^>]+>)*o(?:<[^>]+>)*v(?:<[^>]+>)*e(?:<[^>]+>)*r
```

you only need the ones between each letter if you want to allow tags to break words, like: `This is b<b>old</b>`

This is it without the letter break:

```
hardly(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*\s+(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*able(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*\s+(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*to(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*\s+(?:\s*<[^>]+>\s*)*cover
```

This should work for most cases.  However, if the Html is malformed in which the < or > is not htmlencoded, you may run into issues.  Also it may break on script blocks or other elements with CDATA sections.

Comment: The regex works, but can you explain the pattern? The one with letter break. It's really hard to read and understand for me.

Comment: The letter break is just looking for one or more tags, which is a `<` followed by one more characters that is not a `>`, followed by a `>`

Comment: What I don't understand why do you look for a character that is not `>` instead of a `.` that will match any character. I tested with the dot character and it works fine. So instead of `(?:<[^>]+>)*` I put `(?:<.+>)*`. Why the first would be better that the last?

Comment: So I simplified the expressions: I put `(?:<.+>)*` between letters and `(?:\s*<.+>\s*)*` between words and this works fine.

Comment: Because it doesn't work in some cases. If you use `(?:\s*<.+>\s*)*` between words, then `to(?:\s*<.+>\s*)*home` would match `to<span> never go</span> home` while `(?:<[^>]+>)*` would not match.  This is because `<.+>` matches `<span> never go</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the text in a variable or something, then remove all the tags and perform a normal search in that.
You can use a simple php function [strip_tags()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp).

**EDIT:**
So you might try to look for the first and last words (or just first and then play with the rest of the result) to locate the string, then parse the result and remove tags and check if it's the one you're looking for.
Like using regex:
hardly.*cover
or even
hardly.*$
And saving the location of each result.
Then use strip_tags() on the results and analyze each result if it's the one you want. 
I know it's kinda weird solution but you can avoid endless regex etc.

Comment: I already have a plain text version of the file, actually what I need to do is to find the position of a sub string taken from the plain text version inside the HTML version. So if I find my sub string a the plain text version it won't help, because I already know it's position in the plain text version.